# Woocommerce is_shop not on page slug?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I might be thinking about this the wrong way. Is there a way to check is_shop on a page in a menu? Or inside of a loop of pages?

Psuedo code:

```
foreach($pages as $page) {

    if(is_shop($page)) {
        // Do page something
    }

}
```

My goal is to make a dropdown where the shop page dropdown is styled differently than other dropdowns. So hopefully I could add a class to the shop dropdown menu without having to add it manually through the menu feature.

Not sure it matters, but I'm using Timber for my templates.

Answer (score -1):

Check your HTML `body` classes in a rendered page - you should find that Woocommerce inserts classes when you're on a shop page, so you shouldn't need any custom PHP, just some CSS:

eg, to style something with the class `myfabdropdown` on all normal pages:

```
body .myfabdropdown { background-color: white; }
```

and then to style the same element just on Woocommerce pages:

```
body.woocommerce .myfabdropdown { background-color: yellow; }
```

Comment: While I hadn't thought of checking that I seem to have forgot to mention this is for the primary navigation of the site. So using this method would only add the styles to Woocommerce pages instead of all pages. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: CSS works on everything on your pages. The first line of my example would style normal pages and the 2nd line would override that on Woocommerce pages. I've edited my example to make it a little clearer.